# Saving selected excel sheets in a Listbox as a new workbook/excel file

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, save-as

I have a Listbox in excel named ListBoxSh. The following bits of code generate the name of sheets in the excel workbook and can 'catch' the selected sheets dynamically.

Now what I want is that the sheets that were 'selected' by the user, should be saved as one new excel file (If multiple sheets are selected, they shall all be in ONE file).

It works mostly, but this bit of code doesn't seem to be correct

```
Sheets(SheetArray()).SaveAs Environ("temp") & "\" & FName
```

I have pasted the whole code below. What should I change here?

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Long, d As Long, c As Range, FName As String
FName = "Sheet.xls"

    Dim SheetArray() As String
    
    With ActiveSheet.ListBoxSh
    
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        
            If .Selected(i) Then
    
                ReDim Preserve SheetArray(d)
                SheetArray(d) = .List(i)
                d = d + 1
                
            End If
                    
        Next i
    
    End With
    
Sheets(SheetArray()).SaveAs Environ("temp") & "\" & FName

End Sub
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code. It assumes that the list box is of `ActiveX` type:

```
Sub testSheetListBox()
Dim lbox As MSForms.listBox, i As Long, d As Long, SheetArray()
Set lbox = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ListBoxSh").Object
ReDim SheetArray(lbox.ListCount)

With lbox
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then
                SheetArray(d) = .List(i): d = d + 1
            End If
        Next i
End With
If d > 0 Then
    ReDim Preserve SheetArray(d - 1) 'often ReDim Preserve is not a good way of memory handling
    Sheets(SheetArray).copy 'it creates a new workbook containing the selected sheets...
    ActiveWorkbook.saveas ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Sheet.xls"
Else
    MsgBox "No sheet selected..."
End If
End Sub
```